How to Enable Redirect to Requested URL After Authentication in Angular with angular-oauth2-oidc?
I'm currently working on an Angular Stand-Alone application where I'm using angular-oauth2-oidc for authentication. I have successfully configured authentication using the Authorization Code Flow, but I'm facing an issue with redirecting the user to the originally requested URL after authentication.
Here's a snippet of my current configuration app.config.ts:
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { AuthConfig, OAuthService, provideOAuthClient } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

import { authCodeFlowConfig } from './configurations/auth.config';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, provideHttpClient, withInterceptorsFromDi } from '@angular/common/http';

import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { APP_BASE_HREF, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { FastapiInterceptorService } from './services/fastapi-interceptor.service'

function initializeOAuth(oauthService: OAuthService): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
    oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
    oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin().then(() => {
      resolve();
    });
  });

}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient (
      withInterceptorsFromDi()
    ),
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: FastapiInterceptorService, multi: true},
    provideOAuthClient(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (oauthService: OAuthService) => {
        return () => {
          initializeOAuth(oauthService);
        }
      },
      multi: true,
      deps: [
        OAuthService
      ]
    },
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/matrix' }, // Add this line to provide APP_BASE_HREF
    DatePipe
  ]
};


How can I modify this configuration to ensure that the user is redirected to the originally requested URL after successful authentication? For instance, if a user attempts to access a protected route directly and is redirected to the login page, how can I ensure they are redirected back to the intended route after authentication?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried the below configurations:
Preserve URL State When Logging in With angular-oauth2-oidc

I solved it

function initializeOAuth(oauthService: OAuthService, router: Router): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
      resolve();
      return;
    }
    oauthService.configure(authCodeFlowConfig);
    oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
      const url = oauthService.state ?? '';
      if (!oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
        oauthService.initImplicitFlow(router.url); 
        oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
      }
      else{
        router.navigateByUrl(decodeURIComponent(url));
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
